# MS Word Table Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

In my Word 2016 document, I have sections defined with the Word-standard header levels (e.g. 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1, etc.).

I have tables and figures, and for the first 2 sections of my document, all my tables had been in the lowest-level heading (i.e., section 1.1.1 had table 1.1.1.1 and table 1.1.1.2, and so on.

Now I am in section 3.1, and I have a table there, which I want to be labeled table 3.1.1. However, I can't do this. If I change the caption numbering to "Chapter starts with style Heading 2", it renumbers all of the previous tables, which I don't want.

Eventually, I want section 3.1 to have a table numbered as 3.1.1, and I also want section 3.1.1 to have a table numbered as 3.1.1.1. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a caption and specify that you want to "include the chapter number," Word creates the caption using 2 field codes, for example like this

```
Table { STYLEREF \1 }.{ SEQ \* ARABIC \s 1 }
```

(You can use Alt-F9 on the Windows Desktop version of Word to toggle between "field code" view and "field results view")

The `{ STYLEREF }` field inserts  the "chapter" numbering. The `\1` in there tells Word to treat Heading 1 paragraphs as the chapter headings. But you can manually change the `\1` in the field to `\2`, `\3` etc.

The `\s 1` in the SEQ field tells Word to restart numbering at level 1. Again, you can manually change that so that is is `\s 2`, `\s 3` etc.

So what you need is to use different field coding depending on which level list you want the caption to appear in. So you would probably use

```
Table { STYLEREF \2 }.{ SEQ \* ARABIC \s 2 }
```

for your second-level captions and

```
Table { STYLEREF \3 }.{ SEQ \* ARABIC \s 3 }
```

for your third-level captions.

The problem you are having when you try to do that is that when you use the Caption Numbering dialog box to change the numbering, Word then tries to locate and modify *all* the existing captions in the document. So to achieve what you want you have to avoid using that box (and persuade anyone else working on the document to avoid it.

Usually, the simplest way to avoid the numbering dialog is to set up the captions you want (with no following text) and save then as autotexts or autocorrects. Or just enter them by hand - it's not hard once you get using to using ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of {  }.

Cross-references to these captions will contain all the levels you specified, and a table of Figures/Tables will do so too.

However, this is a manual method - Word isn't going to modify those level numbers automatically if you change the level of the corresponding heading or move the caption to another level. Word won't update any cross-references to them automatically either.

Personally, I would usually try to avid using Word in a way that could be so easily undermined - after all, one change in that dialog box and all your numbering would have to be revisited if you don't click "Undo" pretty fast! But that's just my 2-c worth.